# Detect if user arrived at a page via the back button or otherwise?

Tags: javascript

I have a web app with a lot of native-like interactions such as swiping. Within the app, I track whether they arrived at a page by going forward or back. Then I can do stuff like:

```
if (lastNavDirection === 'back') {
  window.history.forward();
} else {
  window.history.back();
}
```

However, if they exit the app in a browser by entering another URL, then use the browser's back button to get back to my app, I can't call `window.history.forward()` since they'll leave my app. Is it possible to detect if they arrived at my app via the back button?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).